# App Store Sandboxing & Helper Console Application - Errors

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, sandbox, mac-app-store

I've been a Mac App Store Developer for over a year now, and finally I was confronted with Sandboxing, as after a short break I decided today to submit yet another app.

The app consists of :

- one main (status bar only) application (executing the 2nd app in the background)
- one console app (separate project), which I'm including in the former's bundle.

When I tried to submit to the app store, it... politely informed me that the 2 executables were not sandboxed, so I decided to do it.

I first sandboxed my **main app** (added an `XXXX/XXXX.entitlements` file + set the appropriate option under settings). That went fine.

But not with my other **console app**. I did the same thing, but everytime I try to sandbox, it crashes.

I opened app Console and I've noticed some such errors :

> xpchelper reply message validation: sandbox creation failed: 1002

Any ideas? Could you, at least, point me to the right direction?

---

Ahhhh.... this thing will definitely drive me crazy!

Comment: Could you explain more what your console app is about ?

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem??